# for loops in list - replace by location in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I need to take a list add 1 to the first number and then replace the remaining numbers with a 0. I have tried many different ways, but I either only replace the second item or my first item goes away or it doesn't simply work.

Here is what I have:

```
key2=[8,10,10,10]

key2[0]+=1
for item in key2[1:]:
    item=0
    key2.append(item)
```

This is giving me

```
[9, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0]
```

but I need to get rid of all the `10`s. How do I do a for loop to get this result `[9,0,0,0]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
for index in range(1, len(key2)):
    key2[index]=0
```

In this code we are replacing the item from second index to last index by 0.

Answer (score 1):

one liner, using enumerate()

```
lst = [ele+1 if i == 0 else 0 for i, ele in enumerate(lst)]
```

Comment: Well I like list comprehension, too :3

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> key2=[8,10,10,10]
>>> key2[0], key2[1:] = key2[0]+1, [ 0 for item in key2[1:]]
>>> key2
[9, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I would rather use `[0]*len(key2) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range()` to iterate over the indices, till the length of the list, and replace each element by 0.

Code -

```
for i in range(1, len(key2)):
    key2[i] = 0
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> key2=[8,10,10,10]
>>>
>>> key2[0]+=1
>>> for i in range(1, len(key2)):
...     key2[i] = 0
...
>>> key2
[9, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is pushing more zeroes to the end of the list, not overwriting the 10s you want to delete. Instead, try the following:

```
key2=[8,10,10,10]

key2[0]+=1
for num in range (1, len(key2)):
    key2[num] = 0
```

---

```
>>> for num in range (1, len(key2)):
...     key2[num] = 0
... 
>>> key2
[9, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like functional programming:

```
key2 = [8, 10, 10, 10]
key2 = map(lambda (i, v): 0 if i > 0 else v+1, enumerate(key2))

>>> key2
[9, 0, 0, 0]
```

`map` runs through every element of a given list and applies a given function to the element. In my case its the lambda function.

I use enumerate to get the index of the item in the list with the item so I get both information in my lambda function.

#### Detailed explanation:

`enumerate` creates a generator, that for each item of the given list or iterable returns a tuple containing the index of the element in the first position and the element in the second. In the example, it would return:
`[(0, 8), (1, 10), ...]`

`lambda` defines an inline function. In our example, the function takes a tuple and unpacks its values into `i` and `v`. If `i` (the index of our element) is bigger than `0` return `0` if not, return `v+1`.

`map` is a function, that applies a given function (in our case the lambda function) to every element of a given list or iterable (in our case the result of the enumerate). `map` creates a new list with the returned elements of the function.

As `enumerate` and `map` are generators, we are good for memory. However, we basically create a duplicate of the list in memory. We free the memory after reassigning it. So if memory is an issue, don't do this. If not, functional programming is nice :)